# Parse Json to return string or string array?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Can I make these code to one method with generics?

I want return string or string array because my Json file is like below.

[image: Json sample]

So I want to do like this.

```
public static string langFilePath = @"..\..\..\Core\Data\Lang.json";
public static JObject lang = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(langFilePath));

public static string[] GetJsonValue(string key)
{
    string[] values = lang[key].ToObject<string[]>();

    return values;
}
```

But value of key can not be string array.

It can also be string.

Comment: Those look like two completely distinct methods, why do you want to use generics here?  Also, what is even the point of these methods, you throw away the value of `a` anyway?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to C#. Is there a way to do it without using it?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the "a" parameter.

Comment: I want to get values from JSON file, but some properties are string and some properties are string array.

Comment: If you're parsing Json with Json.NET, you may need to provide a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)

Comment: @Stefan I edited my question.

Comment: Why not just make your function return an array every time?  Would make things less complicated.  An array with one member isn't the end of the world.

Comment: Is the structure always like this? In that case you can map it to an object, containing "chooseWhat, searchEnd and wait" as properties, typed resp. string, string[] and string[].

Comment: @stefan No, I will add some more properties.

Comment: Okay, then; why is the first of type string and the rest of string[], is it because choosWhat has only one translation? If so, it should also be a string[] containing 1 element.

Comment: @Stefan OK, I will fix it to array

Comment: In that case: problem solved :-)

Comment: Yes, thank you everyone for your answers. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than returning one of two possible return types, it's *probably* simpler to just coerce a single string to an array containing that string. Assuming you don't control the Json, you probably want to write a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm). Here's my quick and dirty stab at the problem:

```
public class LangEntryConverter: JsonConverter<string[]>
{
    // WriteJson implementation only needed if you need to serialize a value back to Json
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string[] value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value.Length == 1)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(value[i]);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    public override string[] ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string[] existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
                {
                    values.Add((string)reader.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Unexpected token type: {reader.TokenType}");
                }
            }
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            values.Add((string)reader.Value);
        }

        return values.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
// Note: double-quotations are required for C#'s verbatim string syntax; they are not part of the Json
var json = @"{
  ""foo"": ""one"",
  ""bar"": [""one"", ""two"", ""three""]
}";

var lang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json, new LangEntryConverter());
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", lang["foo"]));  // one
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", lang["bar"]));  // one, two, three
```

Of course, in your particular situation, this may require some tweaking.

Comment: @Stefan Agreed, I started to throw this together (really just to refresh myself because it's been at least a year since I worked with Json.NET in depth) before I had seen all the comments. I decided to leave this here anyway just in case it helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use Generic Syntax:

```
 class Program<T>
{

  public static string langFilePath = @"..\..\..\Core\Data\Lang.json";
 public static JObject lang = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(langFilePath));

    public static T GetJsonValue(string key)
    {
        T values = lang[key].ToObject<T>();

        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think the generic parameter is in the wrong place. You have it on `Program` but it should be on `GetJsonValue`. Also, it would probably be helpful to show the calling syntax (i.e. how do you call `GetJsonValue` to get a string vs. a string array).

Comment: Use Object: public static object GetJsonValue(string key)
        {
            object values = lang[key].ToObject<object>();

            return values;
        }

Comment: @MortezaMousavi: Thanks for the follow-up. You can [edit] your question and put the code in there, that way it's easier for others to catch up ;-)

Comment: Ps: I also do think it should be `GetJsonValue<T>` instead of `Program<T>`